# using a dual clause

Tags: clauses

For those who break rules, for them is the punishment.

I see something weird in this structure. It doesn't sound natural. I think 'for them' should be removed only then it will sound natural. The reason why I think so is that this phrase 'for them' is either tautological or perhaps it is even incorrect.

```
For those who break rules, is the punishment.
```

Is it fine?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want your utterance to mean (is it just the general observation *Punishment is for rule-breakers*?), but there's no easy quick fix to make your text syntactically and idiomatically valid. Retaining the "fronting" of the adverbial clause, *For those who break rules, there is punishment* is syntactically valid, but it's an unusual "literary / poetic" construction compared to the standard word order *There is punishment for those who break rules*.

Comment: Punishment is for rule-breakers?    Yes

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Per previous comment, your "inverted" version (with adverbial ***for [them]*** "fronted") is awkward without ***there is*** as in my version. The natural phrasing is simply *[The] punishment is for those who break rules*, where that initial article can be present or not, depending on whether you're talking about punishment in general (a "universal truth" saying), or some particular topic-specific punishment.

Comment: Those who break the rules, the  punishment is for them. Is this fine?

Comment: I can't imagine a context where anyone would say that (you've given no indication of ***what*** punishment, but since you've included the article, you ***must*** be referring to some context-specific punishment), but syntactically it's fine, yes.

Comment: I find your example context a bit "peculiar", so how about ***[Squid Game](https://uk.news.yahoo.com/losers-die-squid-game-macabre-competition-091043321.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAC7guY_fX_s4U4qkVP1Pt0ZuaDtKJee4z-vfTOXrz24KwacZk9obO8UCCP5RxcBG_DxiZUnDJvZU7EaOir20o2yfnmiE1QyZM2sqB6n-I5LKxVLRQUkCd5fvyIrF71ci31HNAwUEjBxJLK4BigtK4eCkZnXmA__RqMCu1xXTDn1a) is for people who like macabre competitions***. Which *could* be resequenced to ***For people who like macabre competitions there is Squid Game***, but that's a bit unlikely.

Comment: FumbleFingers has provided correct examples, such "[The] punishment is for those who break rules," and "There is punishment for those who break rules."  Your first example that uses "for" twice doesn't sound natural.  Your highlighted sentence doesn't sound right either.   Keep in mind that English often depends on standard word ordering.  You should try not to speak like Yoda, with inverted phrasings.   At least, until you are very fluent, and on purpose, it is.